# Find the remainder when $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^5 x^i$ is divided into $f(x^{12})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, contest-math

I am looking for confirmation that this proof works. Feel free to be very pedantic.

We wish to find the remainder when $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^5 x^i$ is divided into $f(x^{12})$. Notice that $f(x)(x - 1) = x^6 - 1$, so let $r$ be a root of $f$. Then $f(r)(r - 1) = 0$ which implies that $r^6 - 1 = 0$, and so $r^6 = 1$. We rewrite the polynomial $f(x^{12})$ into quotient + remainder form as $f(x^{12}) = q(x)f(x) + g(x)$, and so $f(r^{12}) = q(r)f(r) + g(r) = q(r)\cdot0 + g(r) = g(r)$. However, note that $r^{12} = (r^6)^2 = 1$, and so $f(r^{12}) = f(1)$. Now we evaluate $f(1) = \sum_{i=0}^5 1 = 6$, and so the remainder is $6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Let us write $Q(x) := f(x^{12})$. Then indeed: $$Q(x) = f(x^{12})=f(x)q(x)+r(x),$$ where $r$ is a polynomial **of degree at most $4$.**

You noted that $Q(a)=6$ for all $a$ satisfying $a^6=1$, and that the roots of $f$ are $\{a; a^6=1$; $a \not = 1\}$, so that $Q(a)=6$ for each $a$ such that $f(a)=0$, or equivalently, $Q(a)=0$ for each of the roots $a$ of $f$. That is great, but you actually needed to explicitly note is that the equation $Q(a)=6$ holds **for each of the $5 >4 =$deg$(r)$ roots $a$** of $f$. And thus, as $r(a)=6$ for $5 >$ deg$(r)$ values of $a$, it follows that $r$ has to be $6$ everywhere, as the only such polynomial $r$ of degree $4$ or less that satisfies $r(a)$ for $5$ or more values of $a$, is $r(x)=6 \ \forall x$ .

Comment: Hey, sorry, why is this needed?

Comment: Note that $r(x)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $4$. To establish that $r$ is $6$ everywhere you need to evaluate $r$ at at least $5$ points.

Comment: OR you could note that for a $6$-th root $a$ of $1$ that satisfies both $a^3 \not = 1$ and $a^2 \not =1$, there is no polynomial $r$ of positive degree less than $5$ with integral coefficients where $r(a)$ is a rational number. But I don't think that is covered in precal

Comment: Got it. Two more questions: Where did I use $r$ to be the remainder of $Q$ divided by $f$? And the second: What is that theorem called which you used in your latest comment?

Comment: I apologize infact you did not overload $r$ and so I editted that out, I had apparently misread! I'm not sure this result is a theorem per se, this can be proved in a fairly straightforward way given a college course on rings and fields....

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're quite welcome. You did get the crux of it--in both coming up with the right approach, and then in noting that [to use your notation] for any root $r$ of $f$, the equation $f(r^{12})=6$ holds , and thus the equation $g(r)=6$ also holds. You just simply needed to note that $g(r) = 6$ **for all** $5>4=$deg$(g)$ **of the roots** $r$ is what gives $g$ is the $0$-th degeee polynomial that is $6$ everywhere.